# Are the laws of meeting someone affected by phone or video chats?

Tags: halacha, blessing

There are a number of halachot triggered by meeting someone, up to and including saying brachot when you haven't seen them for a long time. Are these halachot affected by phone or video communication? Do we say a bracha over seeing someone by video? Or is the period of absence at least reset by this? Is there possibly a hierarchy of significance: two-way video > one-way video > phone call? What about delayed broadcasts?